# Processing: Sketch gets stuck when using Capture class

Tags: java, processing, video-capture

I'm using Processing 2.0.3 on Windows 8. I tried to use the following code but I've no idea why my sketch couldn't run when I'm using the `processing.video.*` library:

```
import processing.video.*; 
Capture cam; 

void setup() { 
  size(200, 200); 
  cam = new Capture(this);
  cam.start(); 
} 

void draw() { 
  if (cam.available()) { 
    // Reads the new frame
    cam.read(); 
  } 
  image(cam, 0, 0); 
}
```

I notice that the sketch will get stuck and will not open the sketch applet window at all if I call anything related to the `Capture` class. Calling `println(Capture.list());` for example will cause the sketch to stuck at where ever that line was called.

What do I have to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Seems to be a windows 8 or hardware issue, works fine for me in Processing 2.0.3 in OSX. I'd say your best bet to get an answer is probably the Processing forum...

Comment: @PetrosKoutsolampros Thanks. I'm going to make a post on Processing's forum. I have a feeling it has issues with the built-in camera (like the iSight on macbook) on my laptop. I'm not sure though because I tried plugging in an external webcam but I couldn't access it because `Capture.list()` doesn't list the available cameras for me to choose.